# El formato y la extension del archivo de "fichero.xls" no coinciden

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, excel

Cuando salvo un fichero desde angularjs con un contenido y las salvo a un fichero excel. Me sale ese mensaje en excel y no encuentro la solución ya que por más cabeceras que añado sigue saliendo, algunos indican que es por la kb  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948615 otros que es por otra kb e indican que modifque el registro y la configuracion del excel local, pero si sirviendo un fichero excel desde mi web como soluciono esto.

Mi código es tal que asi:

```
 var header = '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">';


        header+='<meta http-equiv="Content-Disposition" content="attachment; filename=contenido_excel.xls">';
        header+='<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />';
        header+='<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />';


        contenido_tabla = document.getElementById('contenido_excel').innerHTML;

        var contenido_muestra= contenido_tabla.replace(/Opciones/g,"");

        var blob = new Blob([header+contenido_muestra ], {

            type: "application/application/application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"

        });
        saveAs(blob, "contenido_excel.xls");
```

Comment: ya probaste con .xlsx?

Comment: Si, he probado con ambas, y cambiando content por application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet tambien mezclado con xlsx y nada , el mismo aviso, que dandole a si , si carga el fichero excel de forma correcta pero lo que quiero es que ese paso no les salga a los clientes.

Comment: y ya probaste aqui `saveAs(blob, "contenido_excel.xls");`?

Comment: hay lo tienes como .xls

Comment: He probado como ambos, al final lo deje como xls por que es el formato más estandar y si había alguna incidencia al respecto, pero aun estando en xls o xlsx no es motivo para que de un erro de ese tipo.

Comment: mmmmmmm dejame ver un poco mas el codigo, pero sigue investigando

Comment: @RafaelLozanoRuiz: .xls es un formato que fue reemplazado en la versión de Excel 2007 por .xlsx, que en mi opinión es "más estándar" que el primero. De hecho, existen varias librerías de código abierto para guardar archivos como .xlsx.